# PHP <a href= click value to cookie

Tags: php, cookies, menu

For a site I use one big PHP file wich generate all the pages, I use url transfer for the menu choice and that's what I want to change.

```
<li><a href="Index.php?s=I">Home<br></a></li>
<li><a href="Index.php?s=Z">About<br></a></li>
```

I want to loose the ?s=Z from the URL and pass the value 'Z' to a cookie when clicked and then reload the PHP file, read the cookie, and generate the page "About".

I was thinking and playing with "onclick", but this didn't work.

Regards,

Marco

Comment: You're probably better off loading the content with AJAX instead, thats the normal approach for cases like this. To make it as easy as possible, you could use the jQuery library, take a look at this method: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Does that mean that the funtions that are now within the main Index.php should be converted to outside php files that are loaded into Index.php after selection?
That part I didn't uderstand in full.

And the main part of the question is unanswerd, how can I give a value from the menu (a href=" to a cookie or a load() command.

Answer (score 0):

With the help on another question I solved also this problem, it's a work around, but it does the trick.

Basicly the solution was to look if there was a VAR at the end of the URL.

If so, put the VAR in a cookie and reload the page without the URL VAR.
After reload, read the cookie and execute the menu option.